# Rails - iterate within has_many ActiveRecord result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

```
Company has_many :profiles, through: :other_model
Profile has_many :companies, through:  :other_model

OtherModel belongs_to :profile
OtherModel belongs_to :company
```

As result of a query, I have a scope of Companies.

What's the more efficacious way to fetch all sub-enteties (profiles)?

Comment: No. I have to_many relationship for profiles (company has many profiles), as some query result I have a number of companies. Now within the same query I need to get all profiles wich belong to these companies. So .to would not help too much here.

Comment: And what about using SQL statement to extract it? I think it'll be the fastest way.

Comment: Any SQL statement examples for this?

Comment: SELECT *
    FROM profiles as P
    WHERE P.company_id = needed_id

Comment: @vsh_ need to see `other_model` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [eager load](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) the profiles when querying the `Company` model:

```
@companies = Company.where(foo: foo).includes(:profiles)
```

Assuming the `where` query on the `Company` returned companies with ids 1,2,3
the above activerecord query should execute following two queries:

```
SELECT * FROM companies WHERE (foo = 'foo')
SELECT profiles.* FROM profiles
  WHERE (profiles.company_id IN (1,2,3))
```

Now the returned `@companies` will include corresponding `profiles` for each company and you could simply do: `@companies.first.profiles` to access the first company profiles

Note, fetching those `profiles` records is done without running any further database queries and this is the hole point of **eager loading**

## Update:

Returned result will be in an `ActiveRecord::Relation` so to fetch all profiles at once you could do:

```
@profiles = @companies.collect(&:profiles)
```

Comment: But as result I have a list of companies, but not profiles for some reasons

Comment: @Nimir Thanks a lot. Looks like that's what I miss right from the beginning.

Comment: @Nimir yea, but turns that this is not exactly what i need. I need to get profiles not only from `@companies.first`, but for all companies in `@companies`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `belongs_to :company` relation in your `Profile` model:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :company

end
```

means that ther is a `company_id` in your `Profile` model.

so you can do:

```
Profile.where(company_id: companies)
```

where `companies` is a `Company` `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

Which results in `SQL`:

```
"SELECT `profiles`.* FROM `profiles` WHERE `profiles`.`company_id` IN (1, 2)"
```

**UPDATE**

Since you use an intermediate model `OtherModel` you can do:

```
Profile.where(id: OtherModel.where(company_id: companies).pluck(:profile_id))
```

Comment: Unfortunately no. I have has_many :profiles, through: other_model

Comment: Then please post all relevant models.